# Parsing date as mm/dd to a DateTime ranged object

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

How do I parse a string eg. "01/21 – 02/20" which is represented as month/day to month/day. How would I go about parsing this to object representation such that I can query many date range objects to find the date range.

Example query would be , 01 / 30 , which would return the date range object for "01/21 - 02/20" as it falls within that particular range.

Comment: what did you meant by `return the date range object`?

Comment: You could turn it into an integer. 01/21 -> 121, 02/20 -> 220, 01/30 -> 130 and just check it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have input string "01/21 – 02/20", then you could parse it by regular expression and then parse matching of regex it into `DateTime`.

Note, that .NET does not contain kind of `DateTime range object` - you should code it yourself.

Your result object should looks like this

```
public class DateTimeRangeObject
{
    public DateTime Date1 {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date2 {get; set;}

    public static DateTimeRangeObject Parse(string inputStr)
    {
        var matches = Regex.Matches(inputStr, "\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}");

        return new DateTimeRangeObject
        {
            Date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(matches[0].Value, "MM/dd", null),
            Date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(matches[1].Value, "MM/dd", null)
        };
    }
}
```

Adding method for check is DateTime value placed between two other values is not too hard.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but does regex 100% work? I'm getting no matches. /Do you know a way of generating my own regex?

Comment: if you have the string in you format - it will work. Example  https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVAmEl

Comment: to get familiar with c# regex, read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx